# Why is the content being sorted by the wrong option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, redux

So I am grabbing movie info from an API. In my page, I have three options in a dropdown for sorting by Alphabet, User Score, and Popularity.

The problem is that when I choose an option it sorts by the option before it. For example, when I choose to sort by User Score, it sorts Alphabetically which is the option before it in the dropdown. And then if I keep choosing options it eventually becomes random and sorts with any of them.

Not sure why this is happening. I'm guessing it has something to do with how I'm setting the state.

Here's my code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {crimeGenre} from "./redux";

class CrimeGenre extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            value: "alphabetically"
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.crimeGenre();
    }

    sortFilms = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        })
        if(this.state.value === "alphabetically"){
            return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
            });
        }else if(this.state.value === "score"){
            return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.vote_average > b.vote_average ? -1 : 1;
            });
        }else if(this.state.value === "popularity"){
            return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.popularity > b.popularity? -1 : 1;
            });
        }
    }

    render(){
        const mappedSelected = this.props.select && this.props.select.map((film, i) => { 
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <h1>{film.title}</h1>
                    <img src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${film.poster_path}`}/>
                    <p>Avg. User Score: {film.vote_average}</p>
                    <p>Popularity Index: {film.popularity.toFixed(0)}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })

            return(
                <div>
                <form>
                    <label>
                        Sort By:
                        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.sortFilms}>
                            <option id="alphabetically" value="alphabetically">Alphabetically</option>
                            <option id="score" value="score">User Score</option>
                            <option id="popularity" value="popularity">Popularity</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </form>
                    {mappedSelected}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

export default connect(state=> state, {crimeGenre})(CrimeGenre);
```

Answer (score 0):

React's `setState()` does not immediately reflect the updation of the state value but creates a pending state transition. Accessing the state after calling `setState()` can potentially return the existing value.

There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Check out the official [ReactJS Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) which explains this better.

---

To make sure your `sortFilms` function uses the new state, pass it as a callback of `setState()` like this:

```
sortFilms = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value}, function () {
        if(this.state.value === "alphabetically"){
            return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
            });
        }else if(this.state.value === "score"){
            return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.vote_average > b.vote_average ? -1 : 1;
            });
        }else if(this.state.value === "popularity"){
            return this.props.select && this.props.select.sort((a, b) => {
                return a.popularity > b.popularity? -1 : 1;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, this did not work, it's still doing the same thing as before.

Comment: Can you please replicate this on codepen and I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to change

First use your select prop to set your initial state like

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: "alphabetically",
            select: props.select
           }
        }
```

You want to do this because you want to cause a re-render whenever select changes(or its order changes) that is why it belongs to the state of your component.

Now coming to your sortFilm function set the state after you have sorted the values like :

```
sortFilms = event => {
  const sorter = event.target.value;
  const films = this.state.select;
  if (sorter === "alphabetically") {
    films.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
    });
  } else if (sorter === "score") {
    films.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.vote_average > b.vote_average ? -1 : 1;
    });
  } else if (sorter === "popularity") {
    films.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.popularity > b.popularity ? -1 : 1;
    });
  }
  //Now we set the state to cause the re-render
  this.setState({ value: sorter, select: films });
};
```

And finally to consume our state that changes whenever we filer we will use our state instead of props like

```
const mappedSelected = this.state.select && this.state.select.map((film, i) => { 
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <h1>{film.title}</h1>
                    <img src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${film.poster_path}`}/>
                    <p>Avg. User Score: {film.vote_average}</p>
                    <p>Popularity Index: {film.popularity.toFixed(0)}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })
```

Now coming to the problem with your code :

You are setting the state that causes a render and is async so when you change your props by sorting them there is no way for the component to know that the props are changed. So, when ever the next re-render is caused it the component updates and starts using the new props, This starts to behave randomly when you start changing the filters quickly as it changes the props multiple times even before the state is set.

The code from AndrewL fails for a similar reason, it sets the state and causes a re-render and then changes the props, the component doesn't have the new prop to update itself there.

Comment: Hey, so you're solution worked, but I did not switch the props with state because when I did that, the data from the API did not load. When I left it as it was with `this.props` instead of `this.state` it worked perfectly, so it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianLopez You do understand why its working right?